# Using React to render a list within a list

Tags: arrays, reactjs, list

I'm very very new to React, and not very experienced in web development as a whole. I'm trying use React to generate a list within a list. I've scanned many postings, and read many documents, but just can't find anything which points me in the right direction.

The basic functionality of my app is to display a list of document titles, and for each title, a number of paragraphs which match an input search string. Text within the paragraphs which matches the search string are highlighted.

So far I have managed to render the title and all the paragraphs in a single element, but I cannot see how to break down the paragraphs into a separate list under the title.

I aware that my existing code style is a bit antiquate, but it's based on the tutorials I've been following. I'm also aware that using "dangerouslySetInnerHTML" is frowned upon, but for the moment, it works.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated. Below are my code, an example of the data I'm trying formatting, and an example of the required output.

Many thanks.

```js
class FoundDoc extends React.Component {
    state = {
        doclist: []
    };

    render() {
        var doclist = this.state.doclist; 
        doclist = doclist.map(function(data){
            return(
                <ul id="doc-details" key={data.title}>
                    <li id="doc-title">{data.title}</li>
                    <ul id="paragraphs" key={data.passages.length}>
                        <li dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: data.passages}} />
                    </ul>
                </ul>

            );
        });
        return(
            <div id="doc-details">
                <form id="search" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <label>Enter Search String:</label>
                    <input type="text" ref="srch" placeholder="Search String" required />
                    <button type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
                <ul>{doclist}</ul>
            </div>
        );
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        var srch = this.refs.srch.value;

        fetch('/api/doclist?srch=' + srch).then(function(data){
            return data.json();
        }).then( json => {
            this.setState({
                doclist: json
            });
        });
    };
}

ReactDOM.render(<FoundDoc />, document.getElementById('doclist'));
```

An example of the data which I'm trying to format:

```js
   [
         {
             title: "Document Title 1",
             paragraphs: [
                 "<em>String</em> 1 found in document",
                 "<em>String</em> 2 found in document"
             ]
         },
         {
             title: "Document Title 2",
             paragraphs: [
                        "<em>String</em> 1 found in document",
                        "<em>String</em> 2 found in document",
                        "<em>String</em> 3 found in document",
                        "<em>String</em> 4 found in document"
             ]
         },
         {
             title: "Document Title 3",
             paragraphs: [
                        "<em>String</em> 1 found in document",
                        "<em>String</em> 2 found in document",
                        "<em>String</em> 3 found in document"
             ]
         }
    ]
```

The desired layout would be:

```
Document Title 1
    a "String 1 found in document",
    b "String 2 found in document"

Document Title 2
    a "String 1 found in document",
    b "String 2 found in document"
    c "String 3 found in document"
    d "String 4 found in document"


Document Title 3
    a "String 1 found in document",
    b "String 2 found in document"
    c "String 3 found in document"
```

Comment: Instead of `<li dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: data.passages}} />` using something like this `data.passages.map((passage, i) =>  <li key={i} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: passage}} />)` perhaps? Or is that not what you intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory you could do the following:

```
var doclist = this.state.doclist; 
    doclist = doclist.map(function(data){
        return(
            <ul id="doc-details" key={data.title}>
                <li id="doc-title">{data.title}</li>
                <ul id="paragraphs">
                {data.passages.map((passage, i) => { //map your passages here.
                    <li key={i}><p>{passage}<p/></li>
                }
                </ul>
            </ul>

        );
    });
```

I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make the HTML as similar as possible to yours even though it can be written much better. This solves your problem without distracting you with the rest.

You need to take care of the keys, try using arrow functions in the maps, destructuring the doc, etc...

```
render() {
  const docs = this.state.docs

  return docs.map(function(doc) {
    return (
      <ul id="doc-details" key={doc.title}>
        <li id="doc-title">{doc.title}</li>
        <li>
          <ul id="paragraphs">
            {doc.passages.map(function (passage) {
              return (
                <li dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: passage}} />
              )
            })}
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    )
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all so much, the app is now working.

As you aIl suggested, I just replaced the line:

```
<li dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: data.passages}} />
```

with

```
 {data.passages.map(function (passage) {
       return (
            <li dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: passage}} />
```

and it worked as planned.

I think I had been close to that on a few occasions, but just hadn't got the correct format.